# Как написать тело функции, удавлетворяющую параметрам

Tags: javascript

Всех приветствую, как написать тело функции

```
function func(){//...}
```

и вызвать её двумя способами с одинаковым результатом

```
func(2, 5) // 7
func(2)(5) // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю решение с бесконечной цепочкой вызовов:

```js
let sum = 0;

function f(...args) {
  args.forEach(arg => sum += arg);
  return f;
}

f(10, 10)(20)(30, 1);

console.log('Результат работы функции:', sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо, еще пара вариантов нашлось тут [ссылка](https://javascript.ru/forum/showthread.php?p=512744#post512744)